# Why i cannot see all my Sender properties that i see via the debugger

Tags: c#, .net, telerik

i have this event that catch value changed event of `RadSpinEditor` (`Telerik` control similar to `Winforms` MunericUpDown):

```
void element_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

When i see the sender via the debugger i can see many properties but when i try to access this via code i cannot see anything except ToString, Equals, getType...
How can i cast `Value` ?
I try `var val = sender as string` but val is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sender is object. You need to cast it into specific control. For your case do this

```
var spinEditor = object as RadSpinEditor;
if (object == null) return;
// Do whatever you want with spinEditor
```